# Given two vectors, get a matrix of boolean values indicating where elements of vectors are equal

Tags: numpy, matrix, vector

I have two vectors: `A` of length `m`, and `B` of length `n`. 
I would like to get an `m` by `n` matrix whose element `(x,y)` is equal to `A[x] == B[y]`.

What's the fastest way to construct this matrix in numpy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`NumPy's broadcasting feature`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) by extending the `A` to a `2D` version with [`None/np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) and then compare against `1D` array B resulting in the desired `2D` boolean array -

```
A[:,None] == B
```

An alternative to creating that `2D` version of `A` would be with reshaping such that the second axis is of `length = 1` . So, an alternative solution would be -

```
A.reshape(-1,1) == B
```

Sample run -

```
In [89]: A
Out[89]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])

In [90]: B
Out[90]: array([4, 3, 2, 1, 0])

In [91]: A[:,None] == B
Out[91]: 
array([[False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```